# Cassandra Spark Connector : requirement failed, contact points contain multiple data centers

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have two Cassandra datacenters, with all servers in the same building, connected with `10 gbps` network. The `RF` is `2` in each datacenter.

I need to ensure `strong consistency` inside my app, so I first planed to use `QUORUM` consistency (`3` replicas of `4` must respond) on both reads and writes. With that configuration, I can also be fault tolerant if a node crash on a particular datacenter.

So I set multiples contact point from multiples datacenter to my spark connector, but the following error is immediately returned : `requirement failed, contact points contain multiple data centers`

So I look at the documentation. It say :

> Connections are never made to data centers other than the data center of spark.cassandra.connection.host [...]. This technique guarantees proper workload isolation so that a huge analytics job won't disturb the realtime part of the system.

Okay. So after reading that, I plan to switch to `LOCAL_QUORUM` (`2` replicas of `2` must respond) on write, and `LOCAL_ONE` on read, to still get strong consistency, and connect by default on `datacenter1`.

The problem, is still consistency, because `Spark apps` working on the second datacenter `datacenter2` don't have strong consistency on write, because data are just asynchronously synchronized from `datacenter1`.

To avoid that, I can set write consistency to `EACH_QUORUM` (= `ALL`). But the problem in that case, is if a single node is unresponsive or down, the entire writes are unable to process.

So my only option, to have both some `fault tolerance`, AND `strong consistency`, is to switch my replication factor from `2` to `3` on each datacenter. Then use `EACH_QUORUM` on write, and `LOCAL_QUORUM` on read ? Is that correct ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comment indicates there is some misunderstanding on your part:

> ... because data are just asynchronously synchronized from datacenter1.

so allow me to clarify.

The coordinator of a write request sends each mutation (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) to ALL replicas in ALL data centres in real time. It doesn't happen at some later point in time (i.e. 2 seconds later, 10s later or 1 minute later) -- it gets sent to all DCs at the same time without delay regardless of whether you have a 1Mbps or 10Gbps link between DCs.

We also recommend a minimum of 3 replicas in each DC in production as well as use `LOCAL_QUORUM` for both reads and writes. There are very limited edge cases where these recommendations do not apply.

The spark-cassandra-connector requires all contacts points to belong to the same DC so:

1. analytics workloads do not impact the performance of OLTP DCs (as you already pointed out), and
2. it can achieve data-locality for optimal performance where possible.